# How to use Git source control in Xcode 7.2?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, version-control

I am using Xcode7.2 and i created new project with “**Source Control- Create Git repository on**” . However this project is created but automatically show popup message like this “***Couldn’t communicate with a helper application***”.

[image]

After this project is created I see the local branch is missing and I can not commit files ("Commit files" does nothing).I also noted following  point like When Xcode is started the following error is presented: "Couldn’t communicate with a helper application". How to solve this issue ? Please help me.

Comment: http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-fix-couldnt-communicate-with-a-helper-application-in-xcode-7/

Answer (score 0):

Try to create git repository from **terminal** if you haven`t created it when creating project.

1. Remove git repository if you have created. (Open **Terminal** go to **git repository** and remove it by `rm -rf .git` )).
2. Go to your XCode project (where **.xcodeproj** file is) and create **git repository** by typing this command `git init`
3. Add files you to your git repository. (`git add --all`)
   (If you want to ignore some files you can create **.gitignore** file in this folder and list files which are you want to ignore)
4. Commit it. `git commit -m "First C"`